# PDO update challenges

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i built an application in mysql, and was having challenges updating records in the db.  Everybody was more interested in telling me that i should just use PDO.
So rather than fight, I decided to start to learn PDO connection and query strings and the practices around using prep stmts.

Anyway in my practice and tutorials, I can pull and parse the information from my database with no challenges. but when it comes to updating or inserting a new record  nothing is ever inserted and I can't find the reason why not.

originally I had a form post to the variables, but that didn't work 
so i hardcoded the variables, but it still isn't working

i could use some help.... can anybody see what is wrong with this insert php script?

```
<?php 
$user="111";
$pass="111";
$database="111";
$host="111";
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);

$event='Special Speaker';
$descript='We have special speakers comming on tuesday night';
$sp1='Speaker Mr.A';
$sp2='Speaker Mr.B';
$date='5-5-15';
$created = '5-5-15';
$id=7;

$stmt=$odb->Prepare("INSERT INTO events(ID,Event,Descript,Sp1,Sp2,Created,Date)
        VALUES (:ID,:Event,:Descript,:Sp1,:Sp2,:Created,:Date");

$stmt->bindParam(':ID',$id);
$stmt->bindParam(':Event',$event);
$stmt->bindParam(':Descript',$descript);
$stmt->bindParam(':Sp1',$sp1);
$stmt->bindParam(':Sp2',$sp2);
$stmt->bindParam(':Created',$created);
$stmt->bindParam(':Date',$date);
$stmt->execute(); 


?>
```

Comment: Enable PDO warnings or exceptions.

Comment: @mario    thanks for the comments.. I've changed the code and added a catch but the error code being thrown is so vague I can't narrow down whats wrong. Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2. it just doesn't tell us where the error is the ' ' are empty –

Comment: Look for Unicode whitespace, backtick-quote column identifiers, and use real prepared statements (instead of PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES), use an `->exec(array(...))` for binding the params alternatively. And there's a closing `)` parenthesis missing.

Comment: @mario  you're my hero!.. it was the fricking missing parenthesis..good catch.. i was ready to pull my hair out and go back to mysql

Comment: I'd advise to toy around with plain PDO for a while; it's definitely simpler than the dated mysql functions. But investigate on a lean wrapper, which can simplify such code to `db("INSERT INTO evnt (:?) VALUES (::)", $row, $row)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may have to specify that your ID is an int like so: `$stmt->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);`
2. Your database may be preventing you from inserting IDs in that table if it's the Identity/Primary column and/or is auto-incrementing.

It'd be a good idea to enable PDO warnings or exceptions so that it can tell you what's wrong or what is failing. See here for more: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php